# Visual Studio Intellisense for custom web components

Tags: visual-studio, web-component, stenciljs

I have some web components custom elements, in this case built with StencilJS.
They are installed into my solution via an npm package and then included globally in a layout via a script tag.

How can I get Visual Studio to know about these elements and provide intellisense for custom elements + their attributes in .cshtml views?

StencilJS outputs a TypeScript *.d.ts file containing definitions for these elements, as well as additional JSON files describing the elements. Can Visual Studio use either of these?

It seems as though Visual Studio Code can be configured to consume this JSON by adding a reference in the `html.customData` setting, does Visual Studio have something equivalent?

Comment: Looks like it's not possible: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27054

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the comment from @Thomas is correct and this is not currently possible:

> Looks like it's not possible: github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27054 – Thomas

I have raised a suggestion here:

<del>https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1244541/intellisense-for-custom-web-components.html?childToView=1245502</del>

edit: marked as duplicate, use this link:

https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-WebComponents-Intellisense/1227195?preview=true

If this is something you'd like to see in Visual Studio, head over and give it a vote so it gets some visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I use `lit-plugin` (for VS Code) and `web-component-analyzer` (for analyzing components) to get real nice code complete and intellisense for my `LitElement` based custom elements. I know Stencil prioritizes JSX over template literals, so `lit-plugin` may or may not help in your case. It was my understanding the Stencil was writing the types for their elements to leverage directly, but it may be that the tools your important don't make those assets appropriately public?

Comment: Thanks, however the question is about Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code.

I have the metadata already output from Stencil, I am looking for a way to make Visual Studio use that metadata.

Comment: I don't see an extension called web-component-analyzer, is this part of the lit-plugin? Or a separate extension?

Answer (score -1):

There's an output target called `docs-vscode` that is not yet documented in the official docs. You can use it in `stencil.config.ts` like

```js
export const config: Config = {
  outputTargets: [
    {
      type: 'docs-vscode',
      file: 'custom-elements.json',
    },
    // ...
  ],
  // ...
}
```

And then set `html.customData` to the path of the json file that Stencil will generate (after you run the build command again).

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to get it running in Visual Studio however, not Visual Studio Code

Comment: I am also looking for a solution for visual studio 2019, I think there I also need custom-elements.json? but how to tell visual studio?